# Could I forgo a database and store all records as "variables" in a node server?

Tags: node.js

I have this node.js program:

```
var x=0;

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    x++;

    response.end(x+"");

}).listen(PORT, ipAddress)
```

I was thinking---why not store all usernames and passwords and everything under the sun as variables outside of the server? Then I wouldn't need a database. I'm a huge beginner when it comes to node. Is this something people do? Are there downsides?

Comment: The memory for the app only lasts as long as the process is running so if the server ever goes down or runs out of memory etc. etc. you will _lose_ all your data. Many databases strive to be durable, i.e. their data lasts even after power failure.

Comment: Hmmm...good point. I suppose servers go down all the time.

Comment: I like how you're trying to utilize the `thinking` part in your work. :) You want to store the data in variables "outside" the server. The point is you need to `store` it anyway. Databases do more stuff than just storing the data. Apart from what @ExplosionPills has pointed out, databases also provide a way for efficient retrival of the requested data. Considering you have hypothetically unlimited memory, even then as your number of records grow, the retrival will become increasingly inefficient. :)

Comment: @AdityaParab in memory data retrieval is always going to be faster than reading from the disk so efficiency is not an issue. Space definitely is one though.

Comment: @ExplosionPills are you sure? There is the overhead of the connection to the database but reading a database is probably faster than scanning an array. Also---what is the memory limit on a node process?

Comment: @NickManning don't know about the memory limit -- I'm not contesting that is an issue. About which is more efficient, using DB indices for retrieval may be faster than certain operations on a (very large) array, but there may be more efficient ways to operate on constructs in the code as well so it's not quite a fair comparison.

Answer (score 0):

When your app terminates, all your data will be lost. So if that data needs to be permanent, it needs to be stored *somewhere*. A database is a fine choice, but if you want to avoid that for whatever reason, you can consider just storing your data in one or more files.

Since you mention passwords, be careful to take appropriate precautions no matter where you store the data. You will likely want to hash your passwords with a cryptographically strong algorithm, and you will want to make sure that access to the data is restricted to only accounts that need it.